# problem in google offline speech recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I own a Samsung galaxy grand 2. I couldn't able to use google offline speech recognition even though i have downloaded offline languages. Is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have to enable "Google now" (google serach service).
I had the same trouble and solved it with this trick.

Hope it may helps you too.